# British equivalent of American "condo"?

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english, british-english, equivalence

In AmE, a condominium (or *condo*) is an apartment that you own. In BrE, the word *flat* is used instead of *apartment*.

**What is, then, the British equivalent of *condo* (i.e., a flat that you own)?**

[Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condominium#:%7E:text=England%20and%20Wales%2C%20UK,-Main%20article%3A%20Commonhold&text=In%20England%20and%20Wales%2C%20the,comprising%2030%20units%2C%20in%20Wales.) that the answer is *commonhold*. However...

1. I have a commonhold.
2. I have a commonhold flat.

How do I use the word?

Comment: I would think that (long) leasehold ownership is more common than commonhold in Britain.

Comment: See also: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/condominium-condo-in-british-english.2960402/

Comment: See also https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condominium.

Comment: According to wikipedia commonhold refers to the shared areas. In my experience (Australia) the word "flat" applies no matter whether it is leased or owned. In ads the type of ownership is specified, but I think the details belong to Legal SE.

Comment: @Peter - "In my experience (Australia) the word "flat" applies no matter whether it is leased or owned. " - same in UK. A flat is a flat, full stop. People might discuss ownership or tenancy matters using appropriate terminology, but there is no single word like 'condo' that is in use.

Comment: Note that in UK [commonhold](https://www.stephens-scown.co.uk/real-estate/what-is-commonhold-ownership/) has only been in use since 2002 and is rare. Usually the property is freehold (you own everything for ever) or leasehold for a flat (you own for it a limited period and rent the infrastructure) or sometimes also for a house (where you don't purchase the land).

Comment: Note that *commonhold* and *leasehold* are particular to England and Wales, Scotland does things differently, NI I have no knowledge of. So far as I understand *condominium* the term applies almost exactly to my property in Scotland, a private flat with shared ownership of the common elements of the structure in which the flat is, elements such as the shared hall- and stairways, roof, etc.  And here they are known as *tenements*.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I seems to be unusual in England to have shared ownership of the common space in a block of flats, leasehold with maintenance charges for the common areas is much more common. If condominiums are like owner-occupied Scottish tenements then there is no real equivalent in England.

Comment: @BoldBen: yes, that seems to be the case, but takes us OT for ELU ...